# Node Red and Socket IO nothing coming to frontend

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io, node-red

I'm trying to send data from node red to react frontend by using socket. Below code giving me no error and I can see there are datas coming to node red by looking at debug screen. But noting coming to frontend side.

Node Red Flow:

```
[
    {
        "id": "83bd68a8f1ff5424",
        "type": "tab",
        "label": "Flow 1",
        "disabled": false,
        "info": "",
        "env": []
    },
    {
        "id": "8ff7f5dc9cc8b36d",
        "type": "tab",
        "label": "Flow 1",
        "disabled": false,
        "info": "",
        "env": []
    },
    {
        "id": "52964918590b507e",
        "type": "subflow",
        "name": "Subflow 1",
        "info": "",
        "category": "",
        "in": [],
        "out": [],
        "env": [
            {
                "name": "event-name",
                "type": "str",
                "value": "opcua"
            },
            {
                "name": "data-type",
                "type": "str",
                "value": ""
            }
        ],
        "meta": {},
        "color": "#DDAA99"
    },
    {
        "id": "c6afd3ef7edc10c0",
        "type": "socket.io-instance",
        "name": "socket.io server",
        "bindToNode": false,
        "port": "3000",
        "options": "{\n  \"cors\": {\n    \"origin\": \"*\",\n    \"methods\": [\"GET\", \"POST\"]\n  }\n}"
    },
    {
        "id": "cb69dabc797703c2",
        "type": "binance-get-price",
        "z": "52964918590b507e",
        "name": "",
        "ticker": "${data-type}",
        "x": 600,
        "y": 160,
        "wires": [
            [
                "6d9eb35e73d66e12"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "b44c637f3081079b",
        "type": "inject",
        "z": "52964918590b507e",
        "name": "",
        "props": [
            {
                "p": "payload"
            },
            {
                "p": "topic",
                "vt": "str"
            }
        ],
        "repeat": "1",
        "crontab": "",
        "once": false,
        "onceDelay": 0.1,
        "topic": "${event-name}",
        "payload": "",
        "payloadType": "date",
        "x": 340,
        "y": 160,
        "wires": [
            [
                "cb69dabc797703c2"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "6d9eb35e73d66e12",
        "type": "change",
        "z": "52964918590b507e",
        "name": "",
        "rules": [
            {
                "t": "set",
                "p": "payload",
                "pt": "msg",
                "to": "$number(payload)",
                "tot": "jsonata"
            }
        ],
        "action": "",
        "property": "",
        "from": "",
        "to": "",
        "reg": false,
        "x": 820,
        "y": 160,
        "wires": [
            [
                "5d2ef76b493aa7b1"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "5d2ef76b493aa7b1",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "52964918590b507e",
        "name": "",
        "func": "\nreturn { payload: { name: msg.topic, value: msg.payload } }",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 1000,
        "y": 160,
        "wires": [
            [
                "b865c5bbf6f5ad74"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "b865c5bbf6f5ad74",
        "type": "socket.io-emit",
        "z": "52964918590b507e",
        "name": "",
        "instance": "c6afd3ef7edc10c0",
        "event": "data",
        "namespace": "",
        "room": "",
        "x": 1160,
        "y": 160,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "28ebf36c23208ad5",
        "type": "inject",
        "z": "8ff7f5dc9cc8b36d",
        "name": "",
        "props": [
            {
                "p": "payload"
            },
            {
                "p": "topic",
                "vt": "str"
            }
        ],
        "repeat": "1",
        "crontab": "",
        "once": false,
        "onceDelay": 0.1,
        "topic": "ns=3;s=\"current_seconds\";datatype=Int32",
        "payload": "",
        "payloadType": "date",
        "x": 250,
        "y": 60,
        "wires": [
            []
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "e27a80efb652855a",
        "type": "socket.io-on",
        "z": "8ff7f5dc9cc8b36d",
        "name": "",
        "instance": "c6afd3ef7edc10c0",
        "event": "connection",
        "namespace": "",
        "x": 295,
        "y": 960,
        "wires": [
            [
                "5a6f46e244b4a266"
            ]
        ],
        "l": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5a6f46e244b4a266",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "8ff7f5dc9cc8b36d",
        "name": "",
        "active": true,
        "tosidebar": true,
        "console": false,
        "tostatus": false,
        "complete": "true",
        "targetType": "full",
        "statusVal": "",
        "statusType": "auto",
        "x": 450,
        "y": 940,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "5c548ac091bf4624",
        "type": "subflow:52964918590b507e",
        "z": "8ff7f5dc9cc8b36d",
        "name": "",
        "env": [
            {
                "name": "data-type",
                "value": "BTCUSDT",
                "type": "str"
            }
        ],
        "x": 520,
        "y": 140,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "f209b4db4df0eb5e",
        "type": "subflow:52964918590b507e",
        "z": "8ff7f5dc9cc8b36d",
        "name": "",
        "env": [
            {
                "name": "event-name",
                "value": "emrecan",
                "type": "str"
            },
            {
                "name": "data-type",
                "value": "BTCTRY",
                "type": "str"
            }
        ],
        "x": 540,
        "y": 60,
        "wires": []
    }
]
```

React Part:

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000/socket.io');

const useSocket = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('data', (msg: string) => {
      console.log(msg);
    });

    // return () => {
    //   socket.off('data');
    // };
  }, []);
```

There is no error in console but also no console log too. Maybe issue with the connection url?
Screenshots from network tab:
[image][image: ][1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: you need to change connection url like this: ws://localhost:3000

Note that my current socket io -v 4.5.2

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a `socket.connect()` prior to your `socket.on` listener?
That might be why you are not getting anything returned. Try this:

```
    import { io } from 'socket.io-client' // Import socket.io

    const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/socket.io');
    
    const useSocket = () => {
      const [data, setData] = useState('');
      useEffect(() => {

        socket.on('data', (msg: string) => {
          console.log(msg);
        });
    
       return () => {

        socket.off('data');

       };

      }, [socket.connected]);
```

Comment: It didn't worked, I added my network tabs ss if that would be helpful

Comment: Hey check the edited version, I think this might solve your issue

Comment: Unfortunately, issue still continues